# how to deal with this libbpf: Error in bpf_create_map_xattr(queue_map):Invalid argument(-22)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf, libbpf

I use libbpf write a bpf program to watch the file open action.
I used BPF_MAP_TYPE_QUEUE to pass the pathname.
It seem worked, but not normally.

```
libbpf: elf: skipping unrecognized data section(8) .rodata.str1.16
libbpf: elf: skipping unrecognized data section(22) .eh_frame
libbpf: elf: skipping relo section(23) .rel.eh_frame for section(22) .eh_frame
libbpf: Error in bpf_create_map_xattr(queue_map):Invalid argument(-22). Retrying without BTF.
******Loop times 0 ******
******Loop times 1 ******
pid=3478152                 cmd=titan_monitor              pathname=
pid=3478152                 cmd=titan_monitor              pathname=/
pid=3478152                 cmd=titan_monitor              pathname=uptime
pid=3478152                 cmd=titan_monitor              pathname=stat
pid=6311                    cmd=python                     pathname=cmdline
pid=6311                    cmd=python                     pathname=proc
pid=6311                    cmd=python                     pathname=sem.1NGcnv
pid=6311                    cmd=python                     pathname=sem.xW06WV
pid=6311                    cmd=python                     pathname=sem.9GYRMO
pid=6311                    cmd=python                     pathname=sem.a5psds
ç******Loop times 2 ******
pid=3478176                 cmd=titanagent                 pathname=
pid=3478152                 cmd=titan_monitor              pathname=urandom
pid=3478152                 cmd=titan_monitor              pathname=/
pid=3478152                 cmd=titan_monitor              pathname=uptime
pid=3478152                 cmd=titan_monitor              pathname=stat
pid=3478152                 cmd=titan_monitor              pathname=cmdline
pid=3478152                 cmd=titan_monitor              pathname=/
pid=3478152                 cmd=titan_monitor              pathname=uptime
pid=3478152                 cmd=titan_monitor              pathname=stat
```

it loss the first value every time in the loop.

```
166     //print out
167     signal(SIGINT, do_quit);
168     int count = 0;
169     while (!quit) {
170         int key = 0;
171         unsigned long long val;
172         struct hash_key hkey = {}, nhkey= {};
173
174         printf("******Loop times %d ******\n", count);
175         count++;
176         memset(&nhkey, 0, sizeof(hkey));
177         while (bpf_map_lookup_and_delete_elem(queue_map_fd, 0, &nhkey) == 0) {
178             printf("pid=%d  \t\t    cmd=%s  \t\t   pathname=%s\n",
179                         (__u32) nhkey.pid,  nhkey.comm,  hkey.pathname);
180             //print_stack(&nhkey, stack_map_fd);
181             hkey = nhkey;
182             //usleep(1000000);
183         }
184
185         usleep(1000000);
186     }
```

```
 37 struct {
 38     __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_QUEUE);
 39     __type(value, struct hash_key);
 40     __uint(max_entries, 10);
 41 } queue_map SEC(".maps");
```

how to deal with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> libbpf: Error in bpf_create_map_xattr(queue_map):Invalid argument(-22). Retrying without BTF.

So, it fails to load initially, but the retry without BTF works, otherwise your program would have exited. I can't be 100% certain but believe this mechanism exists because older kernels do not support providing the BTF info for maps. If that is the case, the warning/error should go away on newer kernels, otherwise something might be wrong with the BTF itself, but I can't tell that from the info provided.

> it loss the first value every time in the loop.

Copying code for refrence

```
166     //print out
167     signal(SIGINT, do_quit);
168     int count = 0;
169     while (!quit) {
170         int key = 0;
171         unsigned long long val;
172         struct hash_key hkey = {}, nhkey= {};
173
174         printf("******Loop times %d ******\n", count);
175         count++;
176         memset(&nhkey, 0, sizeof(hkey));
177         while (bpf_map_lookup_and_delete_elem(queue_map_fd, 0, &nhkey) == 0) {
178             printf("pid=%d  \t\t    cmd=%s  \t\t   pathname=%s\n",
179                         (__u32) nhkey.pid,  nhkey.comm,  hkey.pathname);
180             //print_stack(&nhkey, stack_map_fd);
181             hkey = nhkey;
182             //usleep(1000000);
183         }
184
185         usleep(1000000);
186     }
```

If you follow the code for each iteration of the `while(!quit)` loop:

1. `struct hash_key hkey = {}, nhkey= {};` both hkey and nhkey are initialized.
2. `memset(&nhkey, 0, sizeof(hkey));` hkey is zeroed out
3. The first iteration of the inner loop `bpf_map_lookup_and_delete_elem(queue_map_fd, 0, &nhkey)` you fill `nhkey` with the map value
4. `printf("pid=%d  \t\t    cmd=%s  \t\t   pathname=%s\n",179                     (__u32) nhkey.pid,  nhkey.comm,  hkey.pathname);` then print `nhkey.pid` and `nhkey.comm` which have values. And also `hkey.pathname` but `hkey` is still zero, so nothing it printed.
5. `hkey = nhkey;` you then copy `nhkey` to `hkey` so the next iteration, `hkey` does have a value, but it is the value of the last iteration.

So unless you are using it for something else, you should remove `hkey` from your code and replace your print line with:

`printf("pid=%d  \t\t    cmd=%s  \t\t   pathname=%s\n", 179                         (__u32) nhkey.pid,  nhkey.comm,  nhkey.pathname);`

```
166     //print out
167     signal(SIGINT, do_quit);
168     int count = 0;
169     while (!quit) {
170         int key = 0;
171         unsigned long long val;
172         struct hash_key nhkey= {};
173
174         printf("******Loop times %d ******\n", count);
175         count++;
176         while (bpf_map_lookup_and_delete_elem(queue_map_fd, 0, &nhkey) == 0) {
177             printf("pid=%d  \t\t    cmd=%s  \t\t   pathname=%s\n",
178                         (__u32) nhkey.pid,  nhkey.comm,  nhkey.pathname);
179         }
180
181         usleep(1000000);
182     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, It's very useful! Frequent code changes make my head spin.

Comment: The output problem is solved，I will test the code in higher kernel version.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I tested the code in kernel version 6.3. It works properly。 Than you again.