# libbpf: Error in bpf_create_map_xattr(flow_table):Invalid argument(-22). Retrying without BTF

Tags: ebpf, bcc-bpf, libbpf

I am trying to use `BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY` for tracking new connections and want to maintain a map with tuples and new connection details. I am using `libbpf` framework However, the map creation does not work when either of the key or value is a user-defined struct as shown below:

Note: Have gone through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76801661/how-to-deal-with-this-libbpf-error-in-bpf-create-map-xattrqueue-mapinvalid-a), but my code does not run at all!

```
struct network_tuple
{
    __u32 saddr;
    __u32 daddr;
    __u16 sport;
    __u16 dport;
    __u8 l4_proto;
};

struct syn_event
{
    __u64 time_ns;
    __u32 tcp_seq;
    struct network_tuple flow_key;
};

#define MAX_ENTRIES_FLOW            1

// does not work
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY);
    __type(key, struct network_tuple);
    __type(value, struct syn_event);
    __uint(max_entries, MAX_ENTRIES_FLOW);
} flow_table SEC(".maps");


// works
struct {
     __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY);
     __type(key, __u32);
     __type(value, __u32);
     __uint(max_entries, MAX_ENTRIES_FLOW);
} flow_table SEC(".maps");
```

Code compiles fine but does not get loaded. Output when code is run:

```
libbpf: Error in bpf_create_map_xattr(flow_table):Invalid argument(-22). Retrying without BTF.
libbpf: map 'flow_table': failed to create: Invalid argument(-22)
libbpf: failed to load object 'tp_bpf'
libbpf: failed to load BPF skeleton 'tp_bpf': -22
```

In the [minimal_legacy.bpf.c](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf-bootstrap/blob/master/examples/c/minimal_legacy.bpf.c) code of libbpf-bootstrap repo the comment says "Create an array with 1 entry instead of a global variable which does not work with older kernels", however, with the key and value as __u32 more than 1 max_entries work, but with key and value as network_tuple and syn_event, it does not work even with max_entries equal to 1.

Working on:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
kernel version: 5.15.0-77-generic
```

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY` map type is as the name suggests an array. So the key type of that map must be a 4 byte value (`__u32`). If you want a map with a `struct network_tuple` as key you must use a `BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH` instead.

```
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __type(key, struct network_tuple);
    __type(value, struct syn_event);
    __uint(max_entries, MAX_ENTRIES_FLOW);
} flow_table SEC(".maps");
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Works with BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH